# How to generate random numbers in [0 ... 1.0] in Common Lisp

Tags: random, lisp, probability

My understanding of Common Lisp pseudorandom number generation is that `(random 1.0)` will generate a fraction strictly less than 1.  I would like to get numbers upto 1.0 inclusive.  Is this possible?  I guess I could decide on a degree of precision and generate integers and divide by the range but I'd like to know if there is a more widely accepted way of doing this.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that ? From a purely mathematical point of view, the uniform distribution on [0, 1) or on [0, 1] are undistinguishable, as you have a zero probability of generating 1 in both cases. However, we are talking about computers, and there is no such thing as a continuous function here: depending on your specific use case, this distinction might be important, but I think that it depends on the underlying problem.

Comment: I have used [0,1) for years but recently I looked closely at a book on Genetic Algorithms (Michalewicz, 3ed) and he stipulates [0,1].  Also (without doing any proper analysis, I confess) I had the general impression that the fractions I was generating averaged to be less than 0.5 ... but this was just a feeling I had ... I have not used this all that much in the past and so I must apologise that I am posting this with not a lot of prior forethought.

Answer (score 7):

As you say, `random` will generate numbers in [0,1) by default, and in general `(random x)` will generate random numbers in [0,x).  If these were real numbers and if the distribution really is random, then the probability of getting any number is zero, so this is effectively no different than [0,1].  But they're not real numbers: they're floats, so the probability of getting any particular value is higher since there are only a finite number of floats in [0,1].

Fortunately you can express exactly what you want: CL has a bunch of constants with names like *`-epsilon` which are defined so that, for instance

```
(/= (+ 1.0f0 single-float-epsilon) 1.0f0)
```

and `single-float-epsilon` is the smallest `single-float` for which this is true.

Thus `(random (+ 1.0f0 single-float-epsilon))` will produce random single-floats in the range [0,1], and will eventually probably turn out `1.0f0`.  You can test this:

```
(defun tsit ()
  (let ((f (+ 1.0f0 single-float-epsilon)))
    (assert (/= f 1.0f0) (f) "oops")
    (loop for i upfrom 1
          for v = (random f)
          when (= v 1.0f0)
          return (values i v))))
```

And for me

```
> (tsit)
12839205
1.0
```

If you use double floats it takes ... quite a lot longer ... to get `1.0d0` (and remember to use `double-float-epsilon`).

Comment: Thanks for this response - I feel it does encapsulate my needs very well (and taught me yet another bit about Common Lisp! -  I've used the language since about 1994, but keep finding "black holes" in my knowledge).  I had not thought about using double floats and that might be a good idea for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a different idea here. Instead of trying to stretch the range over an epsilon, we can work with the original range, and pick a victim number somewhere in that range which gets mapped to the range limit. We can avoid a hard-coded victim by choosing one randomly, and changing it from time to time:

```
(defun make-random-gen (range)
  (let ((victim nil)
        (count 1))
    (lambda ()
      (when (zerop (decf count))
        (setf count 10000
              victim (random range)))
      (let ((out (random range)))
        (if (eql out victim) range out)))))


(defun testit ()
  (loop with r = (make-random-gen 1.0)
        for x = (funcall r)
        until (eql x 1.0)
        counting t))
```

At the listener:

```
[5]> (testit) 
23030093
```

There is a small bias here in that the `victim` is never equal to `range`. So that is to say, the `range` value such as 1.0 is never `victim` and therefore always has a certain chance of occurring. Whereas every other value can potentially take a turn at being `victim`, having its chance of occurring temporarily reduced to zero. That should be faintly detectable in a statistical analysis of the output in that the `range` value will occur slightly more often than any other value.

It would be interesting to update this approach with a correction for that, an attempt to do which is this:

```
(defun make-random-gen (range)
  (let ((victim nil)
        (count 1))
    (labels ((gen ()
               (when (zerop (decf count))
                 (setf count 10000
                       victim (gen)))
               (let ((out (random range)))
                 (if (eql out victim) range out))))
      #'gen)))
```

Now when we select `victim`, we recurse on our own function which can potentially select `range`. Whenever `range` is selected as `victim`, that value is correctly suppressed: `range` will not occur in the output, because `out` will never be `eql` to `range`.

We can justify this with the following hand-waving argument:

Let us suppose that the recursive call to `gen` has a slight bias in favor of `range` being output. But whenever that happens, `range` is selected as `victim`, which prevents it from appearing in the output of `gen`.

There is a kind of negative feedback which should almost entirely correct the bias.

---

Note: our random-number-generating `lambda` would be better designed if it also captured a random state object also and used that. Then the sequence it yields would be undisturbed by other uses of the pseudo-random-number generator. That's a different topic.

---

On a theoretical note, note that neither [0, 1) nor [0, 1] yield strictly correct distributions. If we had a mathematically ideal PRNG, it would yield actual real numbers in these ranges. Since that range contains an uncountable infinity of real values, each one would occur with a zero probability: 1/aleph-null, which, I'm guessing, so tiny, that it cannot be distinguished from a real zero.

What we want is the floating-point PRNG to approximate the ideal PRNG.

The problem is that each floating-point value approximates a range of real values. So this means that if we have a generator of values in the range 0.0 to 1.0,    it actually represents a range of real numbers from -epsilon to 1.0 + epsilon.  If we take values from this PRNG and plot a bar graph of values, each bar in the graph has to have some nonzero width.  The 0.0 bar is centered on 0, and the 1.0 bar is centered on 1.   The distribution of real numbers extends from the left edge of the left bar, to the right edge of the right bar.

In order to create a PRNG which mimics an even distribution of values in the 0.0 to 1.0 interval, we have to include the 0.0 and 1.0 values with half probability. So that is to say, when we collect a large number of values from the PRNG, the 0.0 and 1.0 bars of the graph should be about half as high as all the other bars.

Under these conditions, we cannot distinguish the [0, 1.0) interval from the [0, 1.0] interval because they are exactly as large. We must include the 1.0 value, at about half the usual probability to account for the above uniformity problem. If we simply exclude that value, we create a bias in the wrong direction, because the 1.0 bar in the histogram now has a zero value.

One way we could rescue the situation might be to take the 1.0-epsilon bar of the histogram and make that value 50% more likely, so that the bar is 50% taller than average. Basically, we overload that last value of the range just before 1.0 to represent everything up to and not including 1.0, requiring that value to be more likely. And then, we exclude the 1.0 value from the output. All values approaching 1.0 from the left get mapped to the extra 50% probability of 1.0 - epsilon.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond - I'm adopting the other solution only because it is simpler - but it was interesing to read your reflections as well.